# Errors iterating on LinkedList

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list, iterator, duplicates

I'm getting an error for *return* on *method declaration*.

I have a feeling that also my `iterator.element()` is an issue.

#### Trying to find duplicates

I'm attempting to find the duplicates within a `LinkedList` using the *iterator* of `Collection` instead of implementing from scratch.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

  public static removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    ListIterator iterator = list.listIterator(0);

    while (iterator.hasNext()){
      if (set.contains(iterator.element())){
        iterator.remove(iterator.element());
      }
      else{
        set.add(iterator.element());
        iterator.previous = iterator;
      }
      iterator = iterator.next();
    }
    return list;
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create obj of linkedlist
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    list.add(5);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(1);

    System.out.println(removeDupes(list));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates, why aren't you using a Set?

Comment: The `return type` of the function is missing!

Comment: @XO56 You spotted the compilation error – I explained it

Comment: Well formatted code Please clarify: What's your primary question? (1) compiler-error, (2) `iterator.element`, (3) duplicate removal, (4) duplicate finding, or anything else ⁉️

Comment: @hc_dev Greatly appreciate :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the return type in your method declaration.

```
public static removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list){
```

should be

```
public static List<Integer> removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list){
```

If you are trying to find duplicate values this will not be the optimal solution. If you want I could share the one.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(5);
        Function<Set<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> duplicateElements = integerSet -> n1 -> !integerSet.add(n1);
        System.out.println(getDataFromList(list, duplicateElements));
    }

    public static Set<Integer> getDataFromList(List<Integer> linkedList, Function<Set<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> function) {
        Set<Integer> items = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> collect = linkedList.stream()
                .filter(function.apply(items))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return collect;
    }
```

Output:
`[1, 2]`
as 1,2 are the duplicate elements

Comment: Note how your optimization is __changing the behaviour__ that method name expressed: `removeDupes` did remove duplicates from a given list while modifying it! Your implementation `getDataFromList(List<Integer>)` is an immutable (streaming!) transformation, that leaves the given list unmodified. The vague name (not a getter; "data" is most ambiguous everything) is _filtering out = finding the duplicates_.  Improve naming to e.g.`findDuplicates` which may result in a new list containing 0 (empty) upto  ? elements.

Comment: The method requires a predicate along with the input list to perform the operation, so the method doesn’t contain the logic what kind the of data needs to be fetched from the list. If we change the predicate our result will also get changed so that’s why the name of the method is not defined as findDuplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of mistakes, which means you really don't know how to work with `Iterator`. You should look up some kind of "tutorial", e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Now It's not a good code, but it should serve as an example of your mistakes:

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    ListIterator iterator = list.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        // get current Integer with next()
        int current = (Integer) iterator.next();
        if (set.contains(current)) {
            list.remove(current);
        } else {
            set.add(current);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

EDIT: If you don't want to have duplicates, you should use `Set` instead of `List`.

Comment: thank you. and im using a list as input cause im just testing myself if i were to get a list as input how would i filter it to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Highlight the advice: __To avoid duplicates__ (by design) use appropriate _datastructure_ like [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) (allows only _unique_ elements). But __why declare local variable__ `HashSet<Integer> set` which is never returned?

Answer (score 1):

Please *post related error message* as complete output when asking for resolution of an error.

#### How to analyse compiler errors

The **compiler error** is written as ouput on the console:

```
Main.java:5: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public static removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list){
                  ^
```

It's already telling you the exact position: the file and line number (here: line 5 in file `Main.java`) plus visually pointing to the column (here: before `removeDupes`) with a caret like arrow.

The *problem description* for this position:

> error: invalid method declaration; return type required

can be interpreted as *error* in two parts (separated by semicolon):

- in general an **invalid syntax**: "invalid method declaration"
- in detail a **missing requirement**: "return type required"

Note that compiler besides *error* also may output *warning* and *info* messages.

#### What to learn from this error

You will always get this error when your method has no return type declared, before the name. Only method that must not have a return type declared is a *constructor*.

#### How to solve this error

In your case:

- either add a return type matching your *return statement* `return list`, e.g. `LinkedList<Integer> removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list)`
- or add `void` (nothin returned) and removing the *return statement* like `void removeDupes(LinkedList<Integer> list)`